# web api returning invalid json - Unexpected token

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api2 controller returning a collection of complex types.

This setup has been working for some time, until it started choking on a record today.

It appears that one of the objects (out of 122), is now breaking JSON.parse on the client.

Fiddler is also not able to parse JSON. As soon as i skip the "bad" object, valid JSON is returned.

here are the headers from the breaking response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2XEJTR1xBcHBzXENhbXBGb3JjZVx0cnVua1xQZXJtYWwuQlNHLkNhbXBGb3JjZS5XZWJcYXBpXGNhbXBcdGVtcGxhdGVz?=
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 00:50:14 GMT
Content-Length: 1312
```

if i look at the serialized object string on the client, and paste it into jsonLint it points to this area:

```
"HtmlValue": "<html>\n\n<body...
```

this looks pretty much the same as all the "good" objects.. so i'm a bit stumped.

since web api is encoding the response as JSON, why would it allow breaking characters?

**update**

here is the breaking json (i retrieved it on client prior to deserialization:

```
[
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "Id": "00Xg0000000MBGoEAO",
        "Name": "Template Test",
        "Body": null,
        "HtmlValue": "<html>\n\n<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>\n\n<div class=Section1>\n\n<p class=MsoNormal><span class=SpellE><span style='font-size:20.0pt;line-height:\n115%;font-family:\"Franklin Gothic Book\",\"sans-serif\"'></span></span><span\nstyle='font-size:20.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:\"Franklin Gothic Book\",\"sans-serif\"'><o:p></o:p></span></p>\n\n<p class=MsoNormal>testing </p>\n\n<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>\n\n</div>\n\n
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http: //localhost: 61319/6cd9cb905b1e4b5bb51cb5a36ea0bd17/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>\n\n</html>",
        "Subject": "Test",
        "IsActive": true
    }
]
```

the plot thickens.

this part is being inject into the HTML property

```
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http: //localhost: 61319/6cd9cb905b1e4b5bb51cb5a36ea0bd17/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
```

when i step through the code on the server, this snipped is not there, but when i view it in fiddler, i can see it injected in the response!

Comment: Is it possible that there is some strange [encoding/unicode problems](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) with your data? Are you dealing with different operating systems? I've had troubles in the past with Linux preferring \n and Windows preferring \r\n. It's hard to tell without seeing your data.

Comment: the problem field of my object is a html string (of a page). i'm not seeing any specially bad in it..

Comment: Would you please explain more about what the data is, where it's coming from and so on? Can you include a complete (or large) sample of the JSON string? A working sample and a failing sample?

Comment: @RowanFreeman I added the offending json, as retrieved from the browser before calling JSON.Parse